# I am trying to play .m4a file using stream method. but its not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs5, flash-cs3

```
var video:Video = new Video();
addChild(video);
var netCon:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
netCon.connect(null);
var streamNS:NetStream = new NetStream(netCon);
//streamNS.client = this;
//video.attachNetStream(streamNS);
streamNS.play("AfricanElengwen.m4a");
streamNS.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);

function netStatusHandler(e:NetStatusEvent):void
{
    if (e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.FileStructureInvalid")
    {
        trace("The MP4's file structure is invalid.");
    } else if (e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.NoSupportedTrackFound")
    {
        trace("The MP4 doesn't contain any supported tracks");
    }
}
```

I get this code from the below link,
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/hd_video_flash_player.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_0

I didn't get any error.
Can anyone say what is the bug?

Comment: try and add a trace outside any IFs in the netStatusHandler() ... does it get called at all!?

Comment: i used a .flv file. thats playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your .m4a file bit rate or something unsupportable to the flash player. Better way is u can convert it into a mp3 file and then use it.

Comment: yes.. i have converted into mp3 formated. its working fine now... thanks for your suggetion.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through similar issues with the NetStream.Play.FileStructureInvalid error, and after a couple hours of digging around it turns out that this seems to happen in Firefox (PC/Mac) if the server is gzipping the content prior to delivery. In Safari (Mac) and few other browsers, it worked fine.

Using the Live HTTP Headers add-on in Firefox showed that the content-length wasn't being sent along with the response, and I was reminded that it was also being gzipped -- something I didn't consider to be a possible issue.

A quick hack to a local .htaccess file proved gzip to be the culprit. After disabling it, it all worked fine:

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
```

We went back to the Apache config and removed the compression from .mp4 files to do it the right way (removing my earlier hack to the .htaccess), and all works well!